# PHP Explode with Multiple Spaces

Tags: php

I have strings from a database like this:

```
$string1 = "1219.56.C38-.C382                 Codex Azcatitlan";
$string2 = "1219.56.C45-.C452                      Codex Cempoallan";
```

How do I split them up into:

```
["1219.56.C38-.C382", "Codex Azcatitlan"]
["1219.56.C45-.C452", "Codex Cempoallan"]
```

Note if I used $stringar1 = explode(" ", $string1) etc.
I will get this:

```
array(3)
(
    [0] => string "1219.56.C38-.C382"
    [1] => string "Codex"
    [2] => string "Azcatitlan"
)
```

etc.

I need "Codex Azcatitlan"

I do not know in advance how many multiple spaces there are in between the left and right element.
However, we can assume that it will always be more than 1 space.

Comment: `explode(" ", $string1, 2)`

Comment: Why not concat all elements after index 0 which would give you the name?

Comment: Use a regex like `^[^ ]+\s+(.+)$`: https://regex101.com/r/qoyZZN/1

Answer (score 4):

Limit number of parts with third argument of [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) with a combination of [array_map()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to remove unwanted spaces:

```
// this means you will have 2 items and all other spaces 
// after first one  will not be used for `explod`ing
$r = array_map('trim', explode(" ", $string1, 2));
```

Comment: The other spaces are included in the second match though...Also if there are multiple space delimited values on one line this will stop after first.

Comment: @user3783243 sure, spaces are included. But according to OP's array and source string there're a lot of spaces that are dissappeared. So, I presume some filtering is used, here some `trim`ing can also be applied.

Answer (score 3):

Use `preg_split` and check for at least 2 whitespace characters.

```
$string1 = "1219.56.C38-.C382                 Codex Azcatitlan";
$string2 = "1219.56.C45-.C452                      Codex Cempoallan";
print_r(preg_split('/\h{2,}/', $string1));
print_r(preg_split('/\h{2,}/', $string2));
```

https://3v4l.org/oWbIf

If `$string`s also should split on newlines change the `\h` to `\s`. `\h` is a horizontal white space (tab or space), `\s` is any whitespace.

The `{}` creates a range in regex. A single value inside is the number of allowed characters, a `,` inside makes a min and max range. `2` is the minimum and no second value means any number of additional matches. This is the same as the `+` but instead of one match there must be two.

Comment: A tiny bit complicated for a simple problem

Comment: This answer would be complete with an explanation of the pattern (simple, but some people doesn't understand regex)

Comment: Nice solution; it avoids having to remove the spaces afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of `explode()` and `substr()`

```
$string1 = "1219.56.C38-.C382                 Codex Azcatitlan";

// explode() on spaces
$explode = explode( ' ', trim( $string1 ) ); // apply trim() just in case there are ever leading spaces

$result = array(
    $explode[ 0 ], // give me everything before the first space char
    trim( substr( $string1, strlen( $explode[ 0 ] ) ) ) // give me everything starting from the first space char and apply trim()
);

var_dump( $result );
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(17) "1219.56.C38-.C382"
  [1]=>
  string(16) "Codex Azcatitlan"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of `explode()`, `array_shift()`, and `implode()`

```
$string1 = "1219.56.C38-.C382                 Codex Azcatitlan";

// explode() on spaces
$explode = explode( ' ', trim( $string1 ) ); // apply trim() just in case there are ever leading spaces

$result = array(
    array_shift( $explode ), // remove the first element from the array and give me it's value
    trim( implode( ' ', $explode ) ) // $explode has it's first element removed so we can just implode it
);

var_dump( $result );
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(17) "1219.56.C38-.C382"
  [1]=>
  string(16) "Codex Azcatitlan"
}
```

Comment: Yep, this one is smarter than the previous one. Why not posting only 1 answer with both solutions?

Comment: @Cid Thanks. I figured it was different enough to warrant its own answer.

Answer (score -2):

```
preg_match_all('~^[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+\s+([a-zA-Z0-9\s]+)~i', '1219.56.C38-.C382                 Codex Azcatitlan', $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1219.56.C38-.C382                 Codex Azcatitlan
        )

`[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Codex Azcatitlan
    )`

)

Comment: Downvoted because 1) Posted code without any explanation, 2) The output isn't what is expected in OP's question

Comment: what's wrong with you?
1) the code is simple no need to explain.
2) the output is exactly what is needed, read the question please

Comment: It's simple, **but** for someone who don't understand regex. This is definitely **not** the expected result. Read again the question and compare against the index 0 of your output.